# nVidia GeForce 8600gt not working after installing additional driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

After installing additional driver of My nVidia GeForce 8600gt in Ubuntu 11.04, it is not working. The Ubuntu loading dots show full but its not starting.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers/+bug/661248

Answer (score 0):

How did you installed the driver for your graphics card? Did u use jockey-gtk or manually install the driver. If you have installed the driver manually then I will suggest to remove the driver and try jockey-gtk.